# lxc trusty (ubuntu 14.04) network interface is not starting

Tags: 12.04, server, lxc

My host environment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I have created (as root) a container as follows:

> lxc-create -n bitshares2 -t ubuntu -- --release trusty

I first start as a daemon `lxc-start -n bitshares2 -d` then attach using `lxc-attach -n bitshares2`.  Once in the trusty container I see there is no network access.  Other container's are precise (Ubuntu 12.04) and work just fine using the start/attach method.

I reproduced this problem on two Ubuntu 12.04 hosts.

UPDATE: the network interface was down.  This is a manual fix for the problem:

> ifup eth0

Guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/lxc.html

Is this a bug in the template?

Comment: This is an i386 container.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so we can mark this as solved?

Comment: I'm not sure why this template consistently fails to start the network adapter.  I will certainly post the solution when I find one.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind, I now think it was because I had used LWP, and it had mangled my config files. I'm leaving the below info, just in case it was both things.

TLDR: are you dealing with clones of an image? 
If so, make sure you start up the base image (the one created with lxc-create, not lxc-clone) at least once before you clone it.

I was experiencing a similar bug.
On 14.04 host, using 14.04 containers.
I'd snapshot a container, and the first time I ran it, the network would work.
However, if I stopped the container, and then started it up again, the network wouldn't come up: the only way to make it work was to do ifup eth0.

While troubleshooting, I went back to my original image, the first one created with lxc-create. You see, I hadn't started it up: as soon as I created it, I made a snapshot clone to work on, so that I'd always have a nice base image. I noticed, when I ran it, that it's network came up correctly no matter how many times I restarted the container.

Afterwards, every snapshot clone I made off the image worked correctly as well. Meanwhile, the clones I had made before (without running the based container once) continued to not function correctly.

My guess is that there is some initial config that is ran the very first time a newly created container is ran, and this initial config doesn't work correctly if the first run is done as a clone. This is all conjecture though.

Comment: Not a clone, I just ran lxc-create to make it directly from the pre-installed template.